# DataBinder.Eval returns null, although the field is populated

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, data-binding

I am having trouble displaying an object field of one of my entities in an asp.net application. `DataBinder.Eval` returns `Nothing` for some reason.

I have 2 classes as follows:

```
Public Class Bench
    <ScaffoldColumn(False), StringLength(50), Key> _
    Public Property Code() As String

    <Required> _
    Public Property Type() As BenchType

    <Required, StringLength(50)> _
    Public Property Name() As String

    ...
End Class

Public Class BenchType
    <ScaffoldColumn(False), Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)> _
    Public Property ID() As Integer

    <Required, StringLength(50)> _
    Public Property Name() As String

    ...
End Class
```

I am trying to display the `Bench` entities in a `GridView` as follows (with a properly implemented `ObjectDataSource` `odsBenches`):

```
<asp:GridView ID="grwBenches" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsBenches"
    DataKeyNames="Code,Type,Name" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label id="lblCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Code")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bench Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label id="lblBenchType" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Type.Name")%>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

`Code` and `Name` fields are displayed ok, but the `Type` field is shown as empty, this is the resulting markup from the rendered page:

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_grwBenches" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Code</th><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Bench Type</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
                <span id="MainContent_grwBenches_lblCode_0">OK Code</span>
            </td><td>
                <span id="MainContent_grwBenches_lblName_0">OK Name</span>
            </td><td>
                <span id="MainContent_grwBenches_lblBenchType_0"></span>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I step through the code, It appears that `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Type.Name")%>` returns `Nothing` but when I check the database, the `Type` field contains the type code.

What could be the problem?

Edit (DAL code):

```
Public Function GetBenches() As IQueryable(Of Bench)
    Return _db.BENCHES
End Function
```

Where `_db` is the DBContext object.

Comment: You can try <%# DataBinder.Eval("Type") %> and if this is Nothing (it should be the result of <type instance>.ToString())  then your code returns a null Type instance. Database being ok does not mean the code is ok.

Comment: This is indeed the case, but I am using Entity Framework to automatically generate the database from the objects. What should I inspect?

Comment: By this is the case, you mean `<%# DataBinder.Eval("Type") %>` is nothing? In this case, you can check in a small Console app what's going on. Just use the method used by the ObjectDataSource and debug the result it gives. Or if you use SQL Server, have a look in SQL Server profiler.

Comment: In the command window, `? Eval("Type")` returns Nothing. I query the DB and there is a field named `Type_ID` and it is populated with the correct ID. I tried `Eval("Type_ID")`but this resulted in an error.

Comment: I added this line to my DAL object: `Debug.Print(_db.Benches.FirstOrDefault.Type.ToString)` in the output window, I get something like: `Step into: Non-user 'TestTrack.Bench.get_Type'` could this be the reason? The above expression returns Nothing.

Comment: If Type returns nothing, then yes, it definitely explains why Type.Name is also null. DataBinder.Eval just silently fails on null intermediary objects (like Type in this case)

Comment: I used `a = _db.Benches.FirstOrDefault` to see the properties of a. All fields except `Type` are populated properly, `Type` field is nothing.

Comment: @SimonMourier I think I found a direction. It may be something to do with eager/lazy loading and with serialization. Could you please write an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is due the following:

- The `BenchType` object is not serializable
- The `SELECT` method uses lazy loading instead of eager loading

The following changes must be made;

Change the `BenchType` class as follows:

```
<Serializable> _
Public Class BenchType
    <ScaffoldColumn(False), Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)> _
    Public Property ID() As Integer

    <Required, StringLength(50)> _
    Public Property Name() As String

    ...
End Class
```

Change the DAL `SELECT` method as follows:

```
Public Function GetBenches() As IQueryable(Of Bench)
    Return (From c In _db.BENCHES.Include("Type") Select c)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be ?

```
  <asp:Label id="lblBenchType" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BenchType.Name")%>'>
```

since

```
  Public Property Type() As BenchType
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried it, but didn't work.
`BenchType` is the name of the class, it should be the property name.

Comment: have you checked if BenchType returns valid ID and Name ?

Comment: The `Type` field returns `Nothing` therefore `ID` and `Name` fields cannot be accessed

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bench Type">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label id="lblBenchType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Type.Name")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a blind shot, but should you have a New constructor?

```
Public Class Bench
    Public Sub new()
       Me.Type=new BenchType
    End Sub


<ScaffoldColumn(False), StringLength(50), Key> _
Public Property Code() As String

<Required> _
Public Property Type() As BenchType

<Required, StringLength(50)> _
Public Property Name() As String

...
End Class
```

I'm wondering if the database fails to populate because the class hasn't been instantiated.

Comment: EF should be populating the field itself, `Name` and `Code` fields populate effortlessly, there is something about the `Type` field though.

Comment: correct, did you try though? The type isn't a native field, it's a class. Unless it's allocated explicitly, it may be causing an object instantiate error. you can just dim a string and be able to set it's value;memory is allocated on the fly. Not so for a class. You could try changing the class to a struct?

Answer (score 0):

The Eval is looking for the object name and property name and in this case the object is "Type" and the property is "Name".   So to make a long story short, this should work. I think the problem is that 'Type' is a reserved keyword. Try changing the name of your subclass to something more descriptive and see if that makes a difference. I hope this helps.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Id="lblSubclassVal" runat="server" Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubClass.PropertyName")%>"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I tried changing the `Type` to something else, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As

> **[type]** is a User-defined type

```
Public Property Type() As BenchType
```

and

```
Public Class BenchType
    <ScaffoldColumn(False), Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)> _
    Public Property ID() As Integer

    <Required, StringLength(50)> _
    Public Property Name() As String

    ...
End Class
```

> So, you can't normally bind this type in you grid view like

```
 <asp:Label id="lblBenchType" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Type.Name")%>'>
```

or something like

```
<asp:Label id="lblBenchType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type.Name")%>'>
```

***Solution:***

> first of all, you need to convert the result data to the type and then
>   get the required value by its property name.

```
 <asp:Label ID="lb1" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("Type") as BenchType).Name %>'></asp:Label>
```

N:B
i'm Not familiar with Vb.Net, iv'e written the code in C#

Comment: I was able to do it with `Text='<%# Eval("Type.Name")%>'` with eager loading and allowing serialization.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. This does not work if eager loading and serialization are not implemented.